# Determine ambient temperature from health monitoring sensors

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Is it possible to determine the ambient temperature from the health monitoring suite on modern motherboards that among other things can track the CPU temperature?

Comment: Depends on the motherboard, "system" can often be a sencor that resides in the ambient air mostly, on the board somewhere, but it could also be under or around a chip , like the chipset. Some of the newer boards are reading the PCH (the chipset) as a seperate item, some of the older boards system was way more related to the chipset temperatures.  Modern? would still depend on where they put it, but "system" might be the closest thing you could use to feel out the approx ambient.

Answer (score 1):

you mean the room temperature? You might have a sensor that's relatively cool on the motherboard somewhere, but the best you'd get is an "inside the case" temp, almost always warmer than the room. I haven't heard of any onboard "remote sensors" that you could stick on the outside of the case, or even out the window (but that would be fun).

There's probably some USB or wifi remote weather sensors that might work...

Might be better off with a cheap little thermometer stuck to your case or keyboard / monitor / desk.